# Is this similar to the p(A|B) and p(B|A) terms in Bayes Therom?

Tags: bayes-theorem

Say there are a given number of seats at a table, and a given number are filled, and a given number are empty:

Percentage of seats empty = number of seats open / totals seats

Percentage of seats taken = number of seats taken / total seats

Percentage of seats empty + Percentage of seats open = 100%

Is this similar to the p(A|B) and p(B|A) terms in Bayes Therom?

￼

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First "**proportion**" is not always the same as "**probability**". It relies on the contents.

Probably, because we read $P(A|B)$ as "probability of A given B"  you might think "given" is related to conditional probability.

However, conditional Probability $P(A|B)$ means "Probability that event A happens **under the condition** that event B happened".

First, the proportion of the empty seats means what Probability?
Second, "Given number" means "a specific number". It doesn't mean "under the condition". Not related to the conditional probability at all.

Comment: So there isn’t an “upper boundary” in probability, as there is in my example?  The “upper boundary” being the number of seats total?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by probability. Your example doesn't have any experiment (e.g. random selection). For example, if you say "you will select a seat randomly, what is the probability to choose an empty seat?" then we can talk about probability.  Of cause, probability has bounds. It cannot be negative($\ge$0), no more than 100% ($\le$1).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is just the principle of complements.   The sum of the measures of a set and its complement equals the measure of the total.

If $S$ is the set of seats open, and $T$ the set of all seats (so $S\subseteq T$), then the set of seats taken is the relative complement of $S$ over $T$ (ie $T{\smallsetminus}S$).

$$\lvert S\rvert+\lvert T{\smallsetminus}S\rvert=\lvert T\rvert$$

$$$$